# Different layout and constraints for portrait and landscape views in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, constraints

I have 21 UIImageView in my superview and all of them same sized squares.
I want to have 7 rows and 3 column of these UIImageViews in portrait view and when the user change the orientation of the device I want to change it to 3 rows and 7 columns. With constraints and layout option of course.

I couldn't find the way to have different layouts for landscape and portrait modes.

Comment: Have you considered using a `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use Size Classes to handle this situation

just pre-define two layout settings, one for portrait mode, and the other for landscape mode. when display mode changes, UIKit would update layout automatically for you.

for more info and step guides, check Apple's Adaptivity and Sizes guide:

[Adaptive mode intro](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH19-SW1)

[Build adaptive interface using InterfaceBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BuildinganAdaptiveInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH32-SW1)